# function with templates and boost

Tags: c++, templates, boost, functor, boost-bind

I try to write a functor to call a boost function with bind and some template. So i have this main :

```
int     function(char c)
{
   std::cout << c << std::endl;
   return (0);
}

int main()
{
    Function<int (char)> fb = boost::bind(&function, _1);
    fb('c');
    return (0);
}
```

and this is my class `Function` :

```
template<typename F>
class Function
{
private:
    F       functor;

public:
    Function()
    {
        this->functor = NULL;
    };

    Function(F func)
    {
        this->functor = func;
    };

    template <typename P>
    void    operator()(P arg)
    {
        (*this->functor)(arg);
    };

    void    operator=(F func)
    {
        this->functor = func;
    };
};
```

i have a problem : when i try to compile i have these errors :

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' to 'Function<F>'
IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "boost::_bi::bind_t<int, int (*)(char), boost::_bi::list1<boost::arg<1>>>" to "Function<int (char)>" exists
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Read about Type Erasure in C++. Your class doesn't implement it, while `boost::function` and `std::function` in C++11 implement it. I would recommend you to read this article : http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::bind` will return something unspecified, but convertible to a
`boost::function`. There is no reason for you to have your own
`function` class.

Look at this simple example:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

int func(char) { return 23; }

int main()
{
  boost::function<int(char)> bound = boost::bind(func, _1);
  return 0;
}
```

What does that `unspecified` return type mean for your case? You need to erase the type of `Function` and 
need to write something called `AnyFunction`. Why? Because you will never be able to spell out the type of the template argument of `Function` in C++03 (and even C++11, for e.g. accepting only a specific type as a function argument).

Comment: boost::function is forbidden because i have to write a class who is working with `Function<int (char)> f = &function;` and `Function<int (char)> fb = boost::bind(&function, _1);`

Comment: I don't get it. You are writing `Function<...>` but someone else is already using it? Why not just use `boost::function`?

Comment: because it's an exercice and it's forbidden to use this